# Why my react-select make my material ui popup scrollable?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

[image]

My modal component:

```
<Dialog fullWidth={true} sx={{
    "& .MuiDialog-container": {
        "& .MuiPaper-root": {
            maxWidth: maxWidth
        },
    }
}} open={opened} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="parent-modal-title" aria-describedby="parent-modal-description">
    <DialogContent id="modal-description">
        <div>
            {children}
        </div>
    </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

My Select component

```
<Select options={data} placeholder='Choose' value={value} onChange={(e) => { setValue(e) }} theme={(theme) => ({ ...theme, borderRadius: 4, spacing: { ...theme.spacing } })} />
```

My issue is my react-select make my material ui Dialog scrollable.
How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this in my select component

```
 menuPortalTarget={document.body} styles={{ menuPortal: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }) }}
```